# Mine information from facebook?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

I am making a personal (resume type) website.  I was hoping to retrieve all of the data from my facebook page and display it on the about page using the Graph API.

The issue is, it seems like a user always has to give credentials to get an authorization token.  I don't want to require people to log into facebook just to view my page.  I also don't want to login everyone using my credentials (which would mean they would be stored in JavaScript).  Does anyone see a way around this?

I looked into the creating a "page" and using the "page access token" instead.  Then I could get the page access token using my userid stored in JavaScript (in my opinion much better than username and password).  Is there a problem doing it this way?

I would prefer to retrieve this data directly from my account and not have to make a separate "page."  Any and all information is appreciated.  Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be banned in Facebook's [Terms of Service](https://www.facebook.com/legal/terms):

Safety

We do our best to keep Facebook safe, but we cannot guarantee it. We need your help to keep Facebook safe, which includes the following commitments by you:

1. You will not post unauthorized commercial communications (such as spam) on Facebook.
2. **You will not collect users' content or information, or otherwise access Facebook, using  automated means (such as harvesting bots, robots, spiders, or scrapers) without our prior permission.**
3. You will not engage in unlawful multi-level marketing, such as a pyramid scheme, on Facebook.
4. You will not upload viruses or other malicious code.
5. You will not solicit login information or access an account belonging to someone else.
6. You will not bully, intimidate, or harass any user.
7. You will not post content that: is hate speech, threatening, or pornographic; incites 9. violence; or contains nudity or graphic or gratuitous violence.
8. You will not develop or operate a third-party application containing alcohol-related, dating or other mature content (including advertisements) without appropriate age-based restrictions.
9. You will follow our Promotions Guidelines and all applicable laws if you publicize or offer any contest, giveaway, or sweepstakes (“promotion”) on Facebook.
10. You will not use Facebook to do anything unlawful, misleading, malicious, or discriminatory.
11. You will not do anything that could disable, overburden, or impair the proper working or appearance of Facebook, such as a denial of service attack or interference with page rendering or other Facebook functionality.
12. You will not facilitate or encourage any violations of this Statement or our policies.

---

Sorry to be a downer, but I don't think that page scraping is the best way to go.